# Application still open on network after being closed

Tags: c++, networking, process

Basically I am editing some old code (converted from VS2006 to VS2015 project) and both the old code and my new code have a common issue.

The executable is available on the company network for anyone to run. Within the application you open an xml file for editing. The program is used to store and package textures and save the texture information in the xml. The program also logs your actions to a .txt file on the network. The application uses windows forms.

However, after running the program for a while, the program process will remain active on the network once you close it. i.e. on your own computer the process and application have closed, but on the network the process still exists (assigned to you). This prevents the application being deleted, renamed, moved, etc until the process is manually terminated.

The log file is opened and closed as you write to it. The xml is only accessed when saving or loading.

Can anyone think of anything that would cause the application to remain on the network after being closed?

I realise this isn't a lot to go on, just hoping there will be some general causes.

Comment: In Visual Studio, attach to the running process via the Debug menu.  Then choose "Break".  Then you will see what function(s) are being executed in the call stack.

Comment: You should better explain how the application uses the netword: is it a client-server way, or does it only use shared files?

Comment: Hi, sorry. I don't think I was all that clear. It doesn't use the network at all. It is simply accessed over the network rather than locally. (i.e. the executable is placed in a folder on the network and people run it from there. No actual networking in the code itself)